# Algorithm to assign reviewers to essays about their preferred topic

Tags: algorithm

We will receive 180 essays about different topics. Each essay has one or more labels suggesting what topic it is about: history, poetry, art, philosophy, etc
These essays will be reviewed by a pool of 15 reviewers. All of the reviewers prefer reading about certain topic(s), so they have one or more labels attached to them as well.

All of them are however willing to read and review essays that are labeled with a topic that's not on the list of topics they prefer.
Each essay will be read by two reviewers. Each reviewer will read 24 essays.

How can I make sure the essays are distributed in such a way that each reviewer has **the maximum amount of essays about his / her favorite topic(s)**?

1. Make a list of reviewers and their labels, eg *An: poetry / art; Bob: poetry; Cindy: art / philosophy; ...*
2. Strip all the labels in that list that aren't in the list of essay labels.
3. Now start with the reviewers that have only got one label left and distribute the essays with that label evenly among them.
4. Next take the reviewers interested in two topics and distribute them.
5. *(missing these steps)*
6. Last step: take all the essays that can't be matched with a reviewer and use them to fill up the remaining gaps in reviewers' lists, thus ensuring that all the reviewers have 24 essays to read.

I think I know the first steps of the algorithm, but how do  I make sure the distribution maximizes for each reviewer the amount of essays about their favorite topic?

Comment: Your bullet point description is pretty incomplete, the difficulty is hidden behind the word *evenly*. E.g. how do you distribute topics evenly in step 3 when there are e.g. multiple single-topic reviewers A, B and C and multiple essays with topics ABC, AB and A?

Comment: You're correct. I didn't fully think through that step.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood, I thought the bullet points where given to you as a part of the task and your question is about step 5 only. In general, solving via divide and conquer is a pretty good approach which often leads to a greedy and yet optimal solution. In most cases however, a similar problem has already been solved and you can cleverly adapt that solution to your specific problem instance as demonstrated by Peter De Rivaz in his answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using a min cost flow formulation.

The idea is to set up a graph where flow along an edge represents the assignment of an essay to a particular reviewer.

The edges have capacity which means the maximum flow along an edge.  In this case the capacities can be used to control how many reviews are needed per essay, and how many essays each reviewer can handle.

The edges also have weight which allows you to assign a cost to particular combinations.  In this case we can have a cost of 1 if someone is reading a topic they do not prefer.  The weights can adjusted arbitrarily, e.g. if someone really does not want to read essays on algorithms.

Once formulated as a graph, there are standard algorithms to find the minimum cost flow.  My favorite library is Networkx for Python.

### Python code

```
import networkx as nx

reviewers = "An:poetry/art;Bob:poetry;Cindy:art/philosophy".split(';')
essays = "E0:poetry;E1:art;E2:poetry;E3:art/philosophy".split(';')
max_reviews_per_reviewer = 24
max_reviews_per_essay = 2

G = nx.DiGraph()

D = {} # Stores the subjects for each essay
for E in essays:
    essay, subjects = E.split(':')
    G.add_edge('source',essay,capacity=max_reviews_per_essay,weight=0)
    D[essay] = set(subjects.split('/'))

for R in reviewers:
    reviewer,subjects = R.split(':')
    G.add_edge(reviewer,'sink',capacity=max_reviews_per_reviewer,weight=0)
    reviewer_subjects = set(subjects.split('/'))
    for essay,essay_subjects in D.items():
        if essay_subjects & reviewer_subjects:
            G.add_edge(essay,reviewer,capacity=1,weight=0) # Preferred topic
        else:
            G.add_edge(essay,reviewer,capacity=1,weight=1) # Not on preferred topic

mincostFlow = nx.max_flow_min_cost(G, 'source', 'sink')
for R in reviewers:
    reviewer,subjects = R.split(':')
    for essay in D:
        if mincostFlow[essay][reviewer]>0.5:
            print reviewer,essay
```

This code prints out the assignment:

```
An E1
An E0
An E3
An E2
Bob E0
Bob E2
Cindy E1
Cindy E3
```

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful solution! I tried it out in a ipython notebook and it works really nicely. I had to laugh at  you  mentioning the ability to _adjust the weights for reviewers not willing to read about algorithms_. I will certainly read up on graphs if they offer these kinds of solutions.